# Sakai 11 build success Tomcat/portal not running - Catalina Exception starting filter sakai.request java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, sakai

I trying to install Sakai 11 and Tomcat 8, using Maven 3.3.9 have followed https://github.com/sakaiproject/sakai

Sakai compiles properly both times, Tomcat starts but error occurs when I try to access http://localhost:8080/portal. Does anyone have any suggestions or past experience with this? See error logs below:

```
07-Jul-2016 23:23:50.411 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
07-Jul-2016 23:24:03.676 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
07-Jul-2016 23:24:04.696 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Exception starting filter sakai.request
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.sakaiproject.util.RequestFilter.init(RequestFilter.java:649)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
```

Comment: Solved by following a different installation route. :)  https://github.com/csev/sakai-scripts

Comment: I am still curious what caused the problem - I never had it. Tomcat newer than 8.0.32 is known to cause a problem, but not this.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error on Sakai 23.

This error may appear if Sakai is unable to connect to the database.

1. Make sure the database server can be accessed from the machine where Sakai is hosted
2. Make sure database connector jar exists in `Tomcat/lib` folder. For MySql, this file can be downloaded from here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ .